# How to take an object array value in php?

Tags: php, basecamp

Get object 's array value in php

```
 $obj = new Basecamp($bcUrl, $bcApikey, 'X', 'simplexml');
```

while print the object

```
    print_r($obj);
```

Get array as following:

```
Basecamp Object
(
    [request:protected] => 
    [baseurl:protected] => https://test.basecamphq.com/
    [format:protected] => simplexml
    [username:protected] => 5d4dsh8745hkf876kjdfhkfsd843ea46a
    [password:protected] => X
    [request_body:protected] => 
)
```

I want to take value of  [baseurl:protected]  i.e get 'https://test.basecamphq.com/' only from this object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[baseurl:protected]` means that the object has a property called `baseurl` which has a visibility of `protected`. That means you can specifically *not* access it directly from outside the class. Look in the documentation of the class how you're supposed to access it. It probably has a method like `getBaseurl` that allows you to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, its [basecamp-php-api](http://code.google.com/p/basecamp-php-api/) you're using, `Basecamp` class has a `getBaseurl()` method with which the base URL is retrievable.

If it's not, you could extend the `Basecamp` class like this in order to access protected members:

```
class MyBasecamp extends Basecamp {
   public function getBaseurl() {
      return $this->baseurl;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get value of `baseurl` property of `BaseCamp` object outside of it, because it is [`protected`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php). You need to use some getter method.